# Trying to write to file but only prints once

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm writing a small physics engine and I'm learning how to write to a file, what I want to do is print the angle to the `angle.txt` file the same way it does on output. Here's my program:

```
int main() {

ofstream myFile;
myFile.open("angle.txt");


cout << "Insert a lanuch Angle (theta): ";
cin >> thetaDegrees;
cout << "Insert a launch height: ";
cin >> yOld;        
cout << "Insert an initial velocity: ";
cin >> initialVelocity;
cout << "Time (DeltaT) in seconds: ";
cin >> totalT;

for (double deltaTime = 0.0; deltaTime < totalT; deltaTime += 0.1) {

    const double squared = deltaTime * deltaTime;       // squared constant for deltaTime squared

    theta = thetaDegrees * PI / 180;    // converts theta to a degrees value

    // apply initialV to velocity
    velocity = initialVelocity + 9.8 * time;

    yNew = yOld + velocityY * deltaTime - gravitiyHalf * (squared); // calculates Y

    velocityY = velocity - 9.8 * deltaTime; // includes gravity to Y

    angle = atan2(yNew, xNew) * 180 / PI;   // convert angle to degrees

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));     // sleeps for 1 second each loop

    cout << "\nHeight: " << yNew << endl;
    cout << "Angle: " << angle << endl;
    myFile << angle;    // it displays the first value but nothing else!
    myFile.close();

    yOld = yNew;    
}

}
```

When I run this program, the file only shows the first value of angle to the file, after that it ignores the rest. How can I fix this so the `angle.txt` file shows every value of angle?

**EDIT:** I have also tried using `myFile.close();`outside of the for loop but that doesn't work.

Comment: Don't close the file after writing the angle to it, of course. Look at what the code is doing, crystal clear. `myFile << angle; myFile.close();` The first angle is written to the file, and the file is closed. The End. A computer always does what you tell it to do, and not what you want it to do.

Comment: I figured that, but when I close the file outside the loop, it doesn't show anything at all.

Comment: Does it display the correct values when you print them to cout?

Comment: @Harper yes it does, I just want it to continuously write to the file until the loop exits, same way it works with cout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streams are usually buffered. One consequence of this is that characters written to the stream do not appear in the destination until the buffer is *flushed*.

If you do not do anything to flush the buffer, then written characters will not appear until the buffer gets filled up, which will take a rather long time given the rate at which you write to file.

You need to do one of the following:

```
// Option 1
myFile << angle << flush;

// Option 2
myFile << angle;
myFile.flush();
```

If you actually mean for each output to be on a separate line and you just forgot to write out the newlines, then there's yet another option, since this is precisely the use case that `endl` is meant for:

```
// Option 1
myFile << angle << endl;

// Option 2
myFile << angle << '\n' << flush;

// Option 3
myFile << angle << '\n';
myFile.flush();
```

Comment: Note that you probably haven't run into this with `cout` since there is a lot of magic happening to try and make flushes happen even if you forget to specify them.

Comment: Thank you! and thanks for the information on flushing buffers, wasn't aware it worked like that.

Answer (score 0):

Always try to develop new functionality *in isolation*. Try this:

```
int main() {

  ofstream myFile;
  myFile.open("angle.txt");

  for (double deltaTime = 0.0; deltaTime < 2.0; deltaTime += 0.1) {

    cout << "time: " << deltaTime << endl;
    myFile << deltaTime << endl;
  }
  myFile.close();
}
```

If it fails, we can try to tackle this much simpler problem. If it succeeds, you can put some complexity back in...